# Get duplicate elements in a list based on attribute without for loop

Tags: java

I need to get a list of duplicate objects which have one common attribute.

The list has the below mentioned values

```
SomeType someObject1 = new SomeType ("hello1", "1");
SomeType someObject2 = new SomeType ("hello1", "2");
SomeType someObject3 = new SomeType ("hello", "1");
SomeType someObject4 = new SomeType ("hello2", "2");
SomeType someObject5 = new SomeType ("hello2", "1");
SomeType someObject6 = new SomeType ("hello3", "2");
SomeType someObject7 = new SomeType ("hello4", "1");
SomeType someObject8 = new SomeType ("hello5", "2");
```

I need to get objects that share common first parameter 
in this case, someObject1,someObject2 ,someObject4,someObject5 
in a seperate list.

Is there any api available without iterating in for or while loops.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. We now see your input (partially). Show us your desired output, and preferably also what you have tried besides asking us.

Comment: how are exactly your objects equal?

Comment: Why not 1,3,5 and 7 in a list since they all have `"1"` in common? (and the same for 2,4,6 and 8 and `"2"`). Actually if 1,2,4 and 5 should be selected, then this would be extended to all of them because of `"1"` and `"2"`.

Comment: @jlordo I can't see what's unclear. OP's asking if there is a collection that doesn't allow duplicate entries by an attribute or something like that.

Comment: @jlordo OP showed desired output, though we need to know **why** this is the desired output.

Comment: There is no such a thing as going through all the elements on a Collection without a for loop. Even if you are not doing it by yourself, something is doing behind the scenes. This is not the way computing works at all.
What is the problem with writing your custom code as I can see, you need a very specific logic. 
Maybe you should take a look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/

Comment: @AlexanderJardim a `HashSet` doesn't iterate the collection using a straight `for` loop through all the elements (if that's what you meant).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I know there are better data structures them a simple array :D, but I see your point. My comment could interpreted that way.  But you will always need to make some kind of iteration, independent of your structure. And if you are not doing it, someone is doing for you. This is my point.

Comment: @AlexanderJardim I understand your point, but it is better that a library do it for you automatically instead of you doing all the heavy work (and looks like this is what OP searches).

Answer (score 2):

Implement `Object.equals(Object)` and `Object.hashCode(`) according to their contract such that the two input values determine equality and hashCode. Put all objects in a  `HashMap<SomeType, SomeType>`
 using themselves as keys. Then, when you need them, query the hash map using new Objects as keys and you will get exactly the objects you need.

Comment: It would be better using a `Set` backed by `HashSet` instead of a `Map`.

Comment: Also, if you don't want/need to implement `hashCode` nor `equals` method, it would be better using a  `TreeSet` and providing a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Unless I'm missing something, partial elements can't be linearly organized, so `TreeSet` won't really help (or at least won't have any clear advantage over `HashSet`).

Comment: @Dukeling  what do you mean?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A `TreeSet` is obviously linear, since you only have `<`, `=` and `>` (you can represent the all objects, in order, on a straight line). Think how you'd be able to linearly organize objects (without (excessive) duplication) so you'd be able to pick an attribute and a value for this attribute and efficiently query for matching this value. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @Dukeling if by linear you mean the `TreeSet` will have a asymptotic time of O(N) for its operations, then you're having it wrong. It is a balanced red-hat tree (for OpenJDK and probably HotSpot JVM implementations) and at most it will have O(logN) as worst case scenario **always** and will use the provided `Comparator` to handle the elements on the tree balanced.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know operations on a `TreeSet` are O(log n), but my question is - what will the compare function for the `Comparator` look like? How will you be able to define it in such a way to put the required objects close together so you'd be able to run a single query to get all this data? From my (possibly incorrect) interpretation of the question, objects that match on attribute A or B (or others?) must be listed as duplicate. If you order by A first, you'll have to run a query for each possibly value of A (which there could be infinite of) to find elements matching on B.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Now that I think about it, I suppose a viable option is having a separate `TreeSet` for each attribute (as long as there aren't too many attributes).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want all the duplicates. An easy way would be to use the Set collection which allows no duplicates and check for unsuccessfull insertions. For this to work you need to override the equals method from your objects.

```
public List<SomeObject> getDuplicates(List<SomeObject> objects) {
 Set<SomeObject> uniqueObjects = new HashSet<SomeObject>();
 List<SomeObject> duplicates = new ArrayList<SomeObject();

 for(SomeObject so : objects) {
  if(!uniqueObjects.add(so)) {
   duplicates.add(so);
  }
 }
 return duplicates;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use a `HashSet`.

First modify `SomeType` so that both `equals` and `hashCode` use the first field only. Let's assume you've called it `field1`:

- `equals` should only return `true` if both objects' `field1` are equal
- `hashCode` should return `field1.hashCode`

This will cause instances of `SomeType` with identical values for `field1` to be put in the same bucket of the `HashSet`:

```
Set<SomeType> set = new HashSet<SomeType>()
set.add(new SomeType("field1", "foo"))
set.add(new SomeType("field1", "bar"))
// At this point, set only contains SomeType("field1", "bar")
```

If you want to keep all instances, but aggregate them, use a `HashSet` of another collection - say, a `HashSet<ArrayList<SomeType>>`.

Of course, that's if I've understood your question properly...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Guava's Multimaps.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) Then you could do something like this:

```
List<SomeType> someTypes = getSomeTypes();
Multimap<String, SomeType> someTypesByName = Multimaps.index(someTypes, new Function<SomeType, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(SomeType someType) {
        return someType.getName();
    }
}
```

The resulting Multimap, someTypesByName, is essentially a Map of names to the list of SomeType objects with that name.